# High contrast theme and Firefox-Font colour issues?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, colors, themes, user-interface

I have turned on high contrast theme in Windows 7, the problem now is the theme is interfering with firefox( no problem with Opera) and the pages loading. For example, the below given is a screenshot of Firefox after enabling high contrast theme:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhycL.png)
So I did some tweaks in Firefox and got the UI like below
[image]
But, as you can see, the text is still in green colour, I have specified in firefox options to use black colour for text and white for Background and disabled "Use system defaults", now the background colour is white but the text is green. Why it is so?
See this image too:
[image]
Here, there is no problem(I couldn't find the problem in SE sites too)
Why Firefox behaves so strange?
Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to an 11 year old bug!

I actually filed the initial bug report for this behaviour in 2004. It has not been fixed, and was marked as WONTFIX last year. Text input areas are not the only elements that are affected (as described in the bug report), as your example shows, the dropdown lists and buttons are also affected, and do not properly respect the non-system colour setting.

Here is the bug report:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=245485

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox

1. Go to **Options** > **Content** (about:preferences#content)
2. Under "**Fonts and Colors**" hit the button "**Colors...**".
3. In the "**Colors**" popup find the label "Override the colors specified by the page with my selections above:"
4. Select the list item "Never"

[image: helpful screenshot]